# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context (in Linq Contains method)

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a linq to entities query that I am having trouble with.

```
var query = (from q in dc.Table1
                where (from a in dc.Table2 select a.TypeID).Contains(q.TypeID)
                select q);
```

This query is valid in Linq to SQL. It should produce a sql query like this:

```
select * from Table1 where TypeID in (select TypeID from Table2)
```

The error thrown suggests that Linq to Entities is "Unable to create a contstant value of type "Table2"

I could do the following:

```
var typelist = (from q in dc.Table2 select q.TypeID).ToList();

var query = (from q in dc.Table1
                where typelist.Contains(q.TypeID)
                select q);
```

but that would produce 2 sql queries instead of 1:

```
select distinct TypeID from Table2;
select * from Table1 where TypeID in (1,2,3,4,5,6..... etc......);
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with this query and it worked:

```
var result = (from appgroup in test.AppGroupThemes
                      where (from t in test.Themes
                             select t.Id
                            ).Contains(appgroup.ThemeId)
                      select appgroup).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're correct. I've realised that my problem is not with entity framework. I am using BreezeJS and the Breeze EFContextProvider seems to be the real problem.